How to use COUNTUNIQUEIFS in Goole sheets with 2 conditions referencing cells
For example I have this 3 sheets:
SHEET 1 : EVENTS (Have all the info of an event)



EVENT
TYPES
BRANDS




1
3
B1;B2;B3;B7



SHEET 2: EVENTS AND BRANDS



EVENT
BRAND




1
B1


1
B2


1
B3


1
B7



SHEET 3: BRANDS AND TYPE OF BRAND



BRAND
TYPE




B1
1


B2
2


B3
3


B7
1



I am trying to do the formula in SHEET 1, column TYPES:
I think the solution is with COUNTUNIQUEIFS counting the column SHEET 3[TYPE], with the condition it only counts the types of the brands in SHEET 2 [BRAND] that matches the event of SHEET 1 [Event]
BONUS: I was also trying to do the formula of SHEET 1 [BRANDS] with chips, If it were only 1 brand i would use BUSCARV([EVENT];SHEET 2;2;FALSE) but since there would be more than one idk if there is a formula which can write all the brands of each event, with chips or just comas.
Any help greatly appreciated.
I tried this solution How to use COUNTUNIQUEIFS in Goole sheets with an OR condition where a cell can meets two conditions but it doesnt help me since it doesnt refer cells, it just write each one T1 and T2. Since I have different brands and different events it doesnt work for me.

Forgive my ignorance, I don't know what is meant by 'chips' in this context. The information for the chips tag on this site is 'The aim of CHIPS is to enable non-tracking uses of third-party cookies, while preventing cross-site tracking.' which doesn't seem to apply.


Here's a generalized approach which you may adapt accordingly:
=countunique(ifna(filter(xlookup(F2:F;H:H;I:I;);xmatch(E2:E&F2:F;A2&tocol(split(C2;";"))))))



You may try this formula:
=LET(a;FILTER(TOCOL(F2:F;1);TOCOL(E2:E;1)=A2);b;COUNTUNIQUE(BYROW(a;LAMBDA(x;XLOOKUP(x;TOCOL(H2:H;1);TOCOL(I2:I;1)))));c;JOIN(";";a);HSTACK(b;c))

Output:

References:

COUNTUNIQUE
XLOOKUP
JOIN
FILTER

